# Can't see background color css

Tags: css

The class called: codeContainer the background-color isn't being displayed. I think it's underneath the menu bar. However, how can I adjust the background-color or positioning so it's displayed?

http://jsfiddle.net/5qd5bL7o/

```
<div class="codeContainer" id="htmlContainer">
ssd
</div>

<style> .codeContainer { background-color: blue; height: 100%; width: 50%; 
float: left; } </style>
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle uses invalid syntax for your CSS comment.

Comment: remove the `<!-- to clear the floats -->` from the css or change it to `/* to clear the floats */`

Comment: You are using HTML <!-- --> comments in  your code in stead of css /* */ comments. This causes your selector to malfunction. http://jsfiddle.net/5qd5bL7o/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<!-- to clear the floats -->
```

This is an HTML comment, making your CSS invalid. CSS comments are like this:

```
/* to clear the floats */
```

This is not the only occurrence of incorrect comments in your CSS, you should fix them all.

Comment: Yesssssssssssssssssssssssssss !!!!! Working! Wow... I feel like a moron lmao. Thanks Golez and everyone else who contributed!